# Refresh IEnumerable to update month in Calendar

Tags: c#, wpf, calendar, ienumerable, observablecollection

I have created my own calendar with the use of ItemsControl. But to make it fully functionally I need the calendar to display the month that's selected in a ComboBox.

Right now it only displays the current month and lists the items per date in the listbox, but it doesn't update when I change the month or year in the ComboBox.

ViewModel

```
private void RefreshCalendar()
{
    if (CurrentYearItem == 0) return;
    if (CurrentMonthItem == null) return;

    int year = (int)CurrentYearItem;
    int month = Months.IndexOf(CurrentMonthItem) +1 ;

    DateTime targetDate = new DateTime(year,month,1);

    Days= BuildCalendar(targetDate);
}

public IEnumerable<Day> Days { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<Day> BuildCalendar(DateTime targetDate)
{
    DateTime d = new DateTime(targetDate.Year, targetDate.Month, 1);
    int offset = DayOfWeekNumber(d.DayOfWeek);
    if (offset != 1) d = d.AddDays(-offset);

    for (int box = 1; box <= 42; box++)
    {
        var day = new Day { Date = d, Enabled = true, IsTargetMonth = targetDate.Month == d.Month };

        day.IsToday = d == DateTime.Today;
        d = d.AddDays(1);

        var viewSource = new CollectionViewSource
        {
            Source = SceneList
        };

        viewSource.Filter += new FilterEventHandler((o, e) =>
        {
           e.Accepted = (e.Item as Scene).Date == day.Date.ToString();
        });

        day.Scenes = viewSource.View;

        yield return day;
    }
}
```

How do I refresh the IEnumerable each time the value of the combobox changes or is this there another way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement INotifyPropertyChanged Interface.
Here is an example:

```
class ClassTest : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private IEnumerable<Day> myList;
    public IEnumerable<Day> MyList
    {
        get { return myList; }
        set
        {
            if (value != myList)
            {
                myList= value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MyList");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not sure I fully understand your condition. But if I understand it correctly you should try SelectionChangeCommitted event to look up combo box.

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted(v=vs.110).aspx

If you want to look up only user changes in combobox. Do not use SelectedValueChanged because it also raised when the value is changes by the program too.